# How to split an image into multiple smaller images

Tags: java, image, split, sprite

How can I split an Image object (`java.awt.Image`) into smaller images?

For example, splitting a 64*64px image into a sprite sheet of sixteen 16*16px images.

Comment: If the `java.awt.Image` is a `BufferedImage`, this can also be done using `img.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: http://rameshjavablog.blogspot.com/2012/04/sub-image-from-image-using-java.html

Using a function like:

`image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(),new CropImageFilter(13, 13, 143, 163)));`

You are creating an image using the 'crop image filter').

Then it should just be a matter of iterating through the original image grabbing the different squares you want.

Comment: Thx a lot, I am going to use this a lot :)