# Android display larger image

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

I am trying to display a larger image,but it throw OutOfMemoryException.
How to display a larger image, without OutOfMemoryException, don't reduce the picture quality at the same time?? 
display in ImageView.

Comment: Scale down your images. There is only one option.

Answer (score 1):

If image size is too large. Need to scale as below code.

```
      private Bitmap myBitmap;
      try {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                myBitmap = "img_path";

                if (options.outWidth > 3000 || options.outHeight > 2000) {
                    options.inSampleSize = 4;
                } else if (options.outWidth > 2000 || options.outHeight > 1500) {
                    options.inSampleSize = 3;
                } else if (options.outWidth > 1000 || options.outHeight > 1000) {
                    options.inSampleSize = 2;
                }
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                if (myBitmap != null) {
                    try {
                        if (imageView != null) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.gc();
            }
```

For more information go to official [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: this way reduced the image quality

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you divide the larger picture into smaller ones: [How to split an image into multiple smaller images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655388/how-to-split-an-image-into-multiple-smaller-images)

And then put them all together with the help of the standard Layouts of Android.

This is just an idea, I didn't actually tested it or anything.

Hope this helps.